# "Only SunJSSE TrustManagers may be used" when debugging in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jsse, fips

I have very strange behavior when debugging some code in Eclipse 4.3.2 Java 1.7 on Mac.

I have some library (no source code) that probably defining it's own `TrustManager` (my guess). When During debug changing some variable value (not related to the library) and then calling this library I'm getting exception: "FIPS mode: only SunJSSE TrustManagers may be used". If I don't change the value before I call the library then everything is working fine.

What could be a reason for that strange behavior?

Comment: Hi, here is the problem, what code ? The library is a commercial library and I don't have a code, and frankly speaking I don't think it's a library issue, because if I'm not changing variable value (any variable not related to the library, just single bool added for the test) then everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is clear enough : you, for some reasons, enabled the FIPS 140 compliant mode. The FIPS 140 mode makes using the JSSE trust manager mandatory.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/FIPS.html for more information on how to configure, or unconfigure, the FIPS mode, and what are the consequences of enabling it.

Comment: The FIPS not is not enabled, Java or Eclipse thinks that it's enabled, but only I change some variable value in the debug, otherwise Java working fine. Thanks

Comment: Why do you say it isn't when it obviously is. It may not be on purpose, but it is nevertheless. Look for what is enabling it, and fix that.